# Jetty 9.3 and 9.4 fail to start as soon as I apply the keycloak adapter to my jetty_base

Tags: jetty, keycloak

I'm following the basic steps to add security to my app with a keycloak jetty adapter (9.3 and 9.4 tested) but I'm getting an error. The issue is the keycloak adapter because my jetty server starts with no problem from another jetty_base (One without the keycloak adapter)

**Tomas@DESIGN MINGW64** *${JETTY_HOME}/jetty_base java -jar ../start.jar --create-startd --add-to-start=keycloak*

```
INFO: server initialised (transitively) in {jetty.base}\start.ini
    INFO: keycloak initialised in ${jetty.base}\start.ini
    INFO: Base directory was modified
```

**Tomas@DESIGN MINGW64** *${JETTY_HOME}/jetty_base*
*$ java -jar …/start.jar*

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 6: ~ http:\www.apache.org\licenses
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
at java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2234)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.PathMatchers.asPath(PathMatchers.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.PathMatchers.getSearchRoot(PathMatchers.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.PathMatchers.isAbsolute(PathMatchers.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.BaseHome.getPaths(BaseHome.java:356)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.StartArgs.expandModules(StartArgs.java:485)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.processCommandLine(Main.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)

Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
java -jar start.jar --help # for more information
```

Answer (score 1):

The `keycloak.mod` you have has typos and/or bad syntax.

It appears to be searching for a file called `http:\www.apache.org\licenses`, which obviously wouldn't be valid on Windows FileSystem.

Comment: Yeah I'm literally just unzipping and trying to use the adapter they have in the keycloak website. You gave me a good hint though. I looked into the files for the adapter, found the keycloak.mod and I see some genius decided to put some XML comments inside that file. They put # comment lines, and xml comment lines.  Not I'm really getting concerned about the coding quality of this piece of software #keycloak and to use it to protect my apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the keycloak.mod that comes with the Jetty adapter in the keycloak website. Look at the comments using # and the ones using XML comment notation <!--
I just removed the Xml comment section and Jetty comes up with no issues. Thank you @Joakim Erdfelt

```
#
# Keycloak Jetty Adapter
#

[depend]
server
security

[lib]
<!--
  ~ Copyright 2016 Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates
  ~ and other contributors as indicated by the @author tags.
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->

lib/keycloak/*.jar
```

Comment: Why didn't they just use the `[license]` section that is already part of the `<name>.mod` syntax? [See Example](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.39.v20210325/jetty-home/src/main/resources/modules/hawtio.mod#L23-L27)